# In Xubuntu 12.04 - Not finding much of a RAM savings between terminal mode and GUI mode?

Tags: 12.04, xubuntu

I have configured Xubuntu 12.04 to login to terminal without any GUI/DisplayManager.
I could see no process running related to XFCE in `ps -eaf|grep -i xf*`

But my memory consumption in top command does not show any significant improvements.

In GUI mode, the system was taking up 340-350MB of RAM.
In Terminal mode also it taking up the same RAM.

I thought of saving good amount of memory because of No GUI mode;but in vain.
What could be the issue?

Please provide inputs.

Comment: why are you worried about the ram usage? is your PC abnormally slow? Linux will try to use all of your memory every time --- unused RAM is wasted RAM.

Comment: Which particular value of `top` are you using for the comparison? What do you see with `top -b - n 1`? You could put up the data with `top -b -n 1 | pastebinit` (but you need to `sudo apt-get install pastebinit` if you don't have `pastebinit` installed.)

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu Server Edition is good. I misconstrued the output of `top` command.
TOP command Used section reports the total allocated inclusive of caches and buffers which might not be actively used in a running process.

I used `free -m` command to see the memory minus cached minus buffered.
It is around 30-40MB only.

Answer (score 0):

You best bet is probably to install [Ubuntu Server](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server). It is designed to use software and hardware resources in a different way, resulting in less overall RAM and CPU usage for those who need a terminal-only or bare bones setup.